# How to make permutations in an array?

Tags: c, arrays, permutation

I'm new to C, and I was trying to write a function that would make permutations in array, given an array that has the new position of each elements.

An example of what I'd like to have :

```
int newPositions[] = {3,1,5,2,4};
int arr[] = {20,30,-1,9,1};
>> {-1,20,1,30,9}
```

I come from Java, so I had the basic functions we'd think of trying to do that, but I was surprised when I saw that I couldn't return an array in C, and I'm trying to find the best possible way of doing that without using too much memory. I thought about copying the array, but is there another solution?

Thanks

Comment: Pass the result array as a pointer to its first element.

Comment: Asking for the "best way" is generally bad form on SO - it is subjective, and therefore a matter of opinion or target constraints.  Just ask "how" and you will get a number of solutions, hopefully helpfully explained so you can asses the advantages, others will vote and comment and the "best" solution for you will become apparent.

Comment: Note that C array's are indexed from zero, so `{2,0,4,1,3}` would make for a slightly simpler implementation.

Comment: You are asking the the bast way to to implement the function, but in the body explain that your _problem_ is returning an array - that is a different and more general matter.  You might be better off asking how to solve that issue more generically; you may otherwise get lots of clever algorithms and still not know how to resolve the issue of arrays not being first-class data types in C.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how that could look:

```
#include <string.h>

void permutate(int** array, int* newPositions, int count)
{
    int* arrayCopy = malloc(sizeof(int) * count);
    memcpy(arrayCopy, array, sizeof(int) * count);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        array[i] = arrayCopy[newPositions[i] - 1];
    }

    free(arrayCopy);
}
```

Be aware that arrays in C don't know their length (that's why `count` must be passed), so if there's a mismatch between both arrays and/or `size`, your program will do something unexpected or crash.

The are a lot of details to know about arrays and pointers in C. Please have a good look at [this chapter of the famous C-FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html).

Comment: From the example `newPositions[]` in the question, the expression in the loop would need to be:  `array[i] = arrayCopy[newPositions[i] - 1];` since the "positions" are indexed from 1 rather then zero.  That said, it would be better to change the indexes in `newPositions[]` to index from zero, and leave this as-is.